# Creating multiple CombiTimeTable inside a loop

Tags: modelica, dymola

How can I create multiple CombiTmeTable based on a given input number and modify each of their parameters inside a loop?
The desired result is to have a generated number of CombiTimeTables equal to an input n, where each table has different tableName and fileName. I'm new to Modelica, the below code explains the logic but it produces many errors:

```
model DataTables "Model to create CombiTimeTable"

parameter Integer n=10 "Number of tables to be created";

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable B[1](
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="T",
    fileName="path")
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-88,54},{-68,74}})));

equation 
  for i in 2:n loop
   Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable B[i](
            tableOnFile=true,
            tableName="loads",
            fileName="path[i]");
  end for;
end DataTables;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change parameter values in the `equation` section, i.e. during simulation. However, you can do that in an `initial equation` section which is executed before the simulation.

You will also have to mark the parameter that you want to set with `fixed=false` when you instantiate the `CombiTimeTables`. Your code will end up like this (assuming that only `fileName` need to be modified in the loop):

```
model DataTables "Model to create CombiTimeTable"

parameter Integer n=10 "Number of tables to be created";

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable B[1](
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="loads",
    each fileName(fixed=false))
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-88,54},{-68,74}})));

initial equation 
  for i in 2:n loop
   Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable B[i](
            fileName="path[i]");
  end for;
equation
  <remaining equations go here>
end DataTables;
```

Your loop starts from 2. Make sure to assign a value to `B[1].fileName`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Rene!
I managed to solve the issue after including the loop in the initial equation and after making some code adjustments.